# Text blurry external monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro-retina

I recently bought a Samsung monitor (S24E500C) and I connected it to my Macbook pro Retina (15-inch, Early 2013 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M and version 10.11.3) using HDMI-HDMI cable, but the text appears blurry.

It's a common issue for mac's users and, most of them, are able to solve it using a script Ruby that try to force to create a new configuration ([link](http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor)). I also tried this solution, but even if I got a correctly resolution (1920x1080) and a correctly refresh rate (60 Hz), the problem remains.